# Design SQL schema in Visual Studio and auto-generate SQL script to create and upgrade database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, database-scripts

I don't know much about SQL but this is what I want:

1. Visually design an SQL database schema in Visual Studio
2. Let VS generate a create script for this database
3. Track modifications to my schema and automatically generate upgrade SQL scripts
4. Generate entity classes I can use with WCF (without circular ref problems)

Is this possible somehow?

Im using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  Both the year, and the feature set (Pro, Ultimate, Express)?

Answer (score 0):

In know of no way in visual studio to do that. You can however use SQL server management studio. You can enable this by doing:

- Click on "Tools"
- Click on "Options..."
- Click on "Designers"
- Check the checkbox "Auto generate change scripts" as highlighted
  below

Also there are some external tools that enable this like:

http://www.sqldbtools.com/Tools.aspx?ProductId=1

I have used the program from the link above and it works like a charm.